# Problem with installing Winehq stable on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wine, 22.04

I followed the installation steps on https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

When I run the last command `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`, I get this:

```
*Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'prebuilt-mpr.list~a' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package winehq-stable
```

I tried to update but I get this:

```
Hit:1 http://mirror.tedra.es/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirror.tedra.es/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                
Hit:3 http://mirror.tedra.es/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                              
Hit:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu jammy InRelease 
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                   
Hit:6 http://mirror,tedra.es/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                     
Ign:7 https://proget,makedeb.org prebuilt-mpr InRelease    
Get:8 https://proget,makedeb.org prebuilt-mpr Release [1,840 B]
Fetched 1,840 B in 1s (1,420 B/s)  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
N: Ignoring file 'prebuilt-mpr.list~a' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jammy/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'https://proget.makedeb.org prebuilt-mpr InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jammy' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jammy/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://proget.makedeb.org prebuilt-mpr InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jammy' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jammy/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'https://proget.makedeb.org prebuilt-mpr InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jammy' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jammy/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'https://proget.makedeb.org prebuilt-mpr InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jammy' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jammy/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'https://proget.makedeb.org prebuilt-mpr InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jammy' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jammy/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'https://proget.makedeb.org prebuilt-mpr InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jammy' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jammy/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'https://proget.makedeb.org prebuilt-mpr InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jammy' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'jammy/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'https://proget.makedeb.org prebuilt-mpr InRelease' doesn't have the component 'jammy' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no stable build for jammy yet.
You may want to try the Development branch:

`sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-devel`

a description of the differences can be found here:
https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Which_version_of_Wine_should_I_use.3F

files for jammy in the repo:
https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-i386/

where there is if you look here there is a stable version:
https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/impish/main/binary-i386/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running a command calling for a package which is not yet available for Ubuntu 22.04 - you did `$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable` instead run as follow - `$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-stable` ...

It should work not problem.